# Android parser of this code

Tags: android, json, parsing

Need help to parser this json in Android.
Parsing has to be got by URL.  http://www.azmetr.com/view.json
Got a lot tutorials. But couldn't learn how to parse this kind of base.

I used native JSONObject. or is better to use GSON or others?

```
{
   "azmetr":[
      {
         "mebel":{
            "nid":"39",
            "title":"Oturacaq 4"
         }
      },
      {
         "mebel":{
            "nid":"38",
            "title":"Oturacaq 3"
         }
      },
      {
         "mebel":{
            "nid":"37",
            "title":"Oturacaq 2"
         }
      },
      {
         "mebel":{
            "nid":"36",
            "title":"Oturacaq 1"
         }
      },
      {
         "mebel":{
            "nid":"35",
            "title":"Ag kreslo"
         }
      },
      {
         "mebel":{
            "nid":"34",
            "title":"Ag divan"
         }
      },
      {
         "mebel":{
            "nid":"33",
            "title":"Zebra kreslo"
         }
      },
      {
         "mebel":{
            "nid":"32",
            "title":"Zebra divan"
         }
      },
      {
         "mebel":{
            "nid":"31",
            "title":"Korolevski kreslo"
         }
      },
      {
         "mebel":{
            "nid":"30",
            "title":"Korolevski divan"
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? [Here is an example using the standard parser](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/) (but note that you'll most likely get an error about using network operations in the UI thread). There are a lot of good reasons to prefer GSON, I hear, so [here is the official example codes](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide) so you can compare.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use this codes it can parse an json response array. This codes works for me.

```
public void update(){

         try {
                HttpParams httpParams = new BasicHttpParams();
                HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParams, 0);
                HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParams, 0);
                //
                HttpParams p = new BasicHttpParams();
                p.setParameter("user", "1");

                // Instantiate an HttpClient
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(p);                   
                String url = "Your URL";
                Log.i(url, "send  task - start webservice");

                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
                // Instantiate a GET HTTP method
                try {
                    Log.i(getClass().getSimpleName(), "send  task - start");
                    //
                    ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
                    String responseBody = httpclient.execute(httppost,  responseHandler);
                    // Parse
                    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(responseBody);
                    JSONArray jArray = json.getJSONArray("posts");
                    int count = jArray.length();
                    mebel= new String[count];
                    nid= new String[count];
                    title = new String[count];



                    for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject e = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        String s = e.getString("post");
                        JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(s);

                        mebel[i]    =   jObject.getString("mebel");
                        nid[i]  =   jObject.getString("nid");
                        title[i]    =   jObject.getString("title");

                    }


                } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } 
         catch (Throwable t) {
               Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this, "Request failed: " + t.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         }  


    }
```

Note: if you are using 2.3 version or api level 10, you need this codes and put it after your onCreate.

```
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
```

Comment: Thank you for very useful responding. 

Why is this "JSONArray jArray = json.getJSONArray("posts");" ?

Could you please write how is this hierarchy is outputing?

Comment: you can also use "get" as long as they are the same with your web service. if you found my answer useful can you accept it?

Answer (score 0):

Hey no one can teach In `SO All the people is ready to solving problem not teaching`.

please see [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/) example and learn your self if you getting any problem then put comment.